# Differences in work of saveContext() depending of viewController instantination.CoreData Enigma

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

The project has a minimalistic CoreData Stack.

I have one UIViewController subclass "AddOrChangeEntityVC" to create  NSManagedObject, change its properties and write data in DB.

The listed functions work fine if "AddOrChangeEntityViewController" was created from 
MyFirstVC, MySecondVC, ... and MyNinthVC any other viewcontroller exept one BadVC. 
In this case an attempt is made to write an Entity into DB with all properties = nil.

And i see this error.

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=1560 "Multiple validation errors occurred."
```

And for every required property something like

```
"Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=1570 \"firstProperty is a required value.\
UserInfo={NSValidationErrorObject=<APP.Entity: 0x600006917e80> (entity: Entity; id: 0x600000f152a0 <x-coredata:///Entity/t72AEC6D7-A854-40A3-BA9D-5830DFADC8AF2>; data: {\n    firstProperty = nil;\n    secondProperty = nil;\n}), NSValidationErrorKey = firstValue, NSLocalizedDescription=firstValue is a required value"
"Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=1570 \"secondProperty is a required value.\"
```

It should be noted that before saveContext() call all properties are validated.

```swift
AddOrChangeEntityVC: UIViewController {
var entity: Entity?

func saveEntity() -> Bool {
        //validating data

        if !validateData() {
            return false
        }
        //creating passenger
        if entity == nil {

            entity = Entity()
        }
        //saving entity
        if let entity = entity {


            //saving
            entity.firstProperty    = firstPropertyTextfield.text!
            entity.secondProperty   = secondPropertyTextfield.text!
            ...
        CoreDataStack.shared.saveContext()
        return true
    }
 }
```

```swift
Entity: NSManaged

class Entity: NSManagedObject {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Entity> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Entity>(entityName: "Entity")
    }

    @NSManaged public var firstProperty:        String
    @NSManaged public var secondProperty:       String

    convenience init() {
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Entity",
         in: CoreDataStack.shared.persistentContainer.viewContext)!
        self.init(entity: entity, insertInto: CoreDataStack.shared.persistentContainer.viewContext)
            } 
}
```

CoreData Manager

```swift
    class CoreDataStack {

    static var shared = CoreDataStack() 
    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "APP")
    container.loadPersistentStores { storeDesription, error in
          guard error == nil else {
              fatalError("Unresolved error \(error!)")
          }
      }

      // Merge the changes from other contexts automatically. useв for Another Entity
    enter code here
      container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
      container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
      container.viewContext.shouldDeleteInaccessibleFaults = true
      return container
  }()

    func saveContext() {
        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        guard context.hasChanges else { return }
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch let error as NSError{
            print("Error: \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }    
}
```

Transition from anyVC to AddOrChangeEntityVC

````swift
        guard let entityVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "addEntityVC") as? AddOrChangeEntityVC else {return}
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(entityVC, animated: true)
    ```
````

Comment: What is your question? From what you explain your required properties are throwing validation errors when written as nil. That’s expected behaviour. Either mark the properties as optional in your model or supply them with some data.

Comment: Hello, Warren! Thanks for your comment. 
1) Properties should be non-optional. 
2) When i try to save an Entity i assign all the properties of Entity: NSManaged, validate them. ...And then get describrd error. 
3) I want to attract your attention that the presence of an error depends on in which VC i create AddORChangeEntityVC...

I guess that the matter is in NSManagedContext, but not sure

Answer (score 0):

Well, Core Data is misterious and even obscurant.

I made this simple steps. 
1) in AddOrChangeEntityVC i added

```swift
var context: NSManagedObjectContext = CoreDataStack.shared.persistentContainer.newBackGroundContext()
```

2) in initialization of Entity: NSManaged (if we need to create it)

```swift
if entity == nil {
    entity = Entity(context: context)
    }
```

3) unexpectedly facing that after some saving in NSFetchingResultController results added new misterious entity with all properties == nil i filtered results in tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int method and tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell by removing from fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects? elements with some properties == nil.

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
  return fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects?.filter({!$0.firstProperty.isEmpty}).count ?? 0 
}
```

and

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   if fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath).isValid {
        let entity = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
        let cell = UITableViewCell()update(with: entity)
    ....
    }
```